# Connecting to a server through Android 3g and retrieving data from phpmyadmin

Tags: android, phpmyadmin, 3g

I want to create a connection to a server from my Android through 3G but I was unsuccessful.
I succeed if the Android phone is connected through wifi and if it is the same wifi as my server.
Could you help me please and giving my a piece of code to do it?

Here is my code, first, the php which requests my database:

```
<?php
// on se connecte à notre base  pour recuperer les data
$base = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', ''); 
mysql_select_db ('routelibre', $base) ;  
$variable = $_GET['variable'];
$first_token  = strtok($variable, ";;");
$second_token = strtok(";;");
$req =mysql_query("SELECT message from messages where departement='$first_token' AND            voie='$second_token'");
$output=array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($req)) {    
$output[]=$row;    
} 
//on encode en JSON 
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_free_result ($req);  
?>
```

Here is the code for android:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ListActivity;  
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;


 public class ConnexionSQL  {
public void ConnexionSQLActivity(){};

public ArrayList<String> ConnexionBD(String dataFromHMI, Context context) {
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject json_data=null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    ArrayList<String> lesMessages = new ArrayList<String>();

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    try{
        //commandes httpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new 

                    HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1:80/connexion_mysql.php?variable=" + dataFromHMI);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("taghttppost",""+e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(context,e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    //conversion de la réponse en chaine de caractère
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 

        InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("tagconvertstr",""+e.toString());
    }
    //recuperation des donnees json
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {

            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            lesMessages.add(json_data.getString("message"));
            //r.add(json_data.getString("categorie"));

        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Log.i("tagjsonexp",""+e.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.i("tagjsonpars",""+e.toString());
    }
    return lesMessages;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trying to connect locally.

```
HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1:80/connexion_mysql.php?variable=" + dataFromHMI);
```

Do you have your code on a server that you can access while not connected to your local machine? That is the url you need to post to!

192.168.1.1 is the default IP address used by Linksys routers (and maybe others?) See: http://www.tech-faq.com/192-168-1-1.html

So, when you are connected over wifi to this router than you able to access sources stored @192.168.1.1:80 but over 3g you are no longer connected to this router. You will need to host your files in another way...by setting up a server, hosting your files through a web hosting service, etc... in order to access the files remotely!

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't make sense...I was a little rushed...feel free to ask questions

Comment: I have no server, it is only on my computer.Can you explain better I did not understand?

Comment: Well, part of that is a decision you're going to have to make! If you choose to host your files using a web hosting service than I'd suggesting looking at this list: http://www.top10bestwebhostings.com/index.php?kw=best%20web%20hosting&c=24561268058&t=search&p=&m=e&adpos=1t1&a=201&gclid=COOSxuCnl7ECFUFV4AodmWWheg

Comment: Okay, if I host my database, how the source code will be impacted?

Comment: I'm not sure of other alternatives or how to implement them!

Comment: Well, once you choose a web hosting service then they should have instructions on how to connect in various ways. It depends on the service you choose sometimes!

Comment: its usually pretty simple once you set up your domain

Comment: "Okay, if I host my database, how the source code will be impacted?" I'm not sure I understand this question! The source code is what you make it!

Comment: excuse my English (I am French). What are the changes to Java code?

Comment: ooo yes so I believe the only thing you should need to change is "HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1:80/connexion_mysql.php?variable=" + dataFromHMI);" to the new url which will be based on where you host your code. I would start with getting the host set up and then go from there.

Comment: I hope this helps. I'll be gone for a bit so I wont be able to answer more ?'s!